# using request.static_url() in a pyramid app

Tags: python, pyramid, static-files

In a pyramid application, I defined a static view for serving css/js files and another one to serve others datas like uploaded files:

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
config.add_static_view('uploads', path='/data/uploads')
```

On the template side, i'm using **request.static_url()** to access to static files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('myapp:static/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js')}"></script>
```

The problem is I don't know how to use **request.static_url()** with the second definition (uploads), what i did never works and crash the app:

```
${request.static_url('uploads/a_named_file')}
```

Can you just explain me how to do please?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: 'crash the app': Please, always include the full traceback in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include the full path:

```
${request.static_url('/data/uploads/a_named_file')}
```

Static assets are looked up based on the matching path you registered for the static assets. For your two static view registrations, you use the paths `static` and `/data/uploads`, respectively. The first one is relative to `myapp`, but the second one is an absolute path. When using an absolute path for a static view, you need to use the *same* absolute path when generating static URLs.

Comment: thank you, it works. It wasn't obvious to use an absolute path as it will be different on 2 different installations... that's why i put an upload_dir variable in the ini file and access by request.registry.settings.get('upload_dir').